# How can I write Persian words Left-to-Right?

Tags: html, css, text-direction

I need to write Persian words in left to right mode for write Math formula in `textarea html css` but I cant get it working with `direction:ltr;` or other solutions to fixed it with direction.

I tested **align-text**, **direction**, **dir Attribute** and another things...

I want my result is equals to this:

User writes: سجاد+آرش+تست+تست

HTML input Show this: تست + تست+ آرش + سجاد

Comment: Hi, Sajjad! Have you tried to google it? It is very hard to start looking for a solution without knowing your code. In any case, I found something that might help with your problem - [look at this one](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/reversing-text/).

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you write تست+آرش , the HTML see it one word and just when you use space (" ") HTML break your word.

**You can place your Persian words inside ( and ).**

So instead using this:
سجاد+آرش+تست+تست

**use this:
(سجاد)+(آرش)+(تست)+(تست)**

Comment: Yeah our use something like this to solve problem thanks to ask. we use <p> in content-editable elements html